# Trying to 'make install' xmr-stak

Tags: mining

By following the instructions from the readme on github for Ubuntu/Debian:

## Ubuntu / Debian

```
sudo apt install libmicrohttpd-dev libssl-dev cmake build-essential libhwloc-dev
git clone https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak.git
mkdir xmr-stak/build
cd xmr-stak/build
cmake ..
make install
```

Once I put in 'make install' I get this:

```
suhdood@suhdoodpc:~/Desktop/xmr-stak/build$ make install
Scanning dependencies of target xmr-stak-c
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_blake256.c.o
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_groestl.c.o
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_jh.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_keccak.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_skein.c.o
[ 17%] Linking C static library bin/libxmr-stak-c.a
[ 17%] Built target xmr-stak-c
Scanning dependencies of target xmr-stak-backend
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/jconf.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/version.cpp.o
In file included from /home/suhdood/Desktop/xmr-stak/xmrstak/version.cpp:1:0:
/home/suhdood/Desktop/xmr-stak/xmrstak/version.hpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string get_version_str()’:
/home/suhdood/Desktop/xmr-stak/xmrstak/version.hpp:13:33: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
  return std::string(ver_long) + std::to_string(uint32_t(fDevDonationLevel * 1000)) ;
                                 ^
CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/version.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/version.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:180: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

UPDATE: Some people in IRC #monero-pools suggested that I needed gcc version 6 or higher. So I did this:

`sudo apt-get install gcc-7`

`gcc --version` still gave me version 5.4.2

so I did this:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 70 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7`

then `gcc --version` came back with 7.2.0

then I was able to make install past 23%, but got stopped again at 70% here:

```
suhdood@suhdoodpc:~/Desktop/xmr-stak/build$ make install
Scanning dependencies of target xmr-stak-c
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_blake256.c.o
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_groestl.c.o
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_jh.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_keccak.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/c_skein.c.o
[ 17%] Linking C static library bin/libxmr-stak-c.a
[ 17%] Built target xmr-stak-c
Scanning dependencies of target xmr-stak-backend
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/jconf.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/version.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/hwlocMemory.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/jconf.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/minethd.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/backendConnector.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/globalStates.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/cpu/crypto/cryptonight_common.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/http/httpd.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/http/webdesign.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/misc/console.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/misc/executor.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/misc/telemetry.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/misc/utility.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/net/jpsock.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-backend.dir/xmrstak/net/socket.cpp.o
[ 67%] Linking CXX static library bin/libxmr-stak-backend.a
[ 67%] Built target xmr-stak-backend
[ 70%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
CMake Error at xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o.Release.cmake:222 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/suhdood/Desktop/xmr-stak/build/CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/./xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o


CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/build.make:70: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Highlighted:

```
/usr/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
```

So which is it? I get errors with both GCC versions.... >.<

Answer (score 2):

CUDA needs older gcc (in your case gcc-5). Try another gcc-5 from: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/